# Sort and Display XML Output in Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, foreach

I've got a file called file.xml formatted as such:

```
<Sources>
  <add id="TestName" type="TestType" priority="1">
    <parameters>
      <otherIdentifiers>TestNameIdentifier</otherIdentifiers>
      <reportSource>TestReportSource</reportSource>
      <activeStatus>true</activeStatus>
      <UploadStatus>false</UploadStatus>
      <displayTypes>Image\,Report</displayTypes>
      <address.host>192.168.1.2</address.host>
    </parameters>
  </add>
  <add id="TestName2" type="TestType" priority="2">
    <parameters>
      <otherIdentifiers>TestName2Identifier</otherIdentifiers>
      <reportSource>TestReportSource2</reportSource>
      <activeStatus>true</activeStatus>
      <UploadStatus>false</UploadStatus>
      <displayTypes>Image\,Report</displayTypes>
      <address.host>192.168.1.3</address.host>
    </parameters>
  </add>
</Sources>
```

In Powershell I declare my file as:

```
[xml]$File = gc file.xml
```

The specific values I'm interested in are

```
$File.Sources.add.id
$File.Sources.add.type
$File.Sources.add.priority
$File.Sources.add.parameter.activeStatus
$File.Sources.add.parameter."address.host"
```

I know that I can get them each individually as formatted above, but I'm struggling to figure out how to display the information for each add node by itself formatted in a table as:

```
Source     Type     Priority     Active     IP Address
```

And the last thing I'm struggling to figure out is how to sort this by priority.  These sources are sorted in the order they were added, and sometimes a newer source gets a higher priority, so they're not necessarily in that order.

If anyone is able to help point me in the right direction, I'd be greatly appreciative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use calculated properties. 
This will get you started:

```
$f.Sources.add | Select-Object @{n='Source';e={$_.id}}, @{n='Type';e={$_.type}}, @{n='Priority';e={$_.priority}} | Sort-Object -Property Priority
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you!  Once I added the FT to the end, it did exactly what I was looking for!